# Frequency counter input on myDAQ not working

Tags: labview

I'm trying to measure the speed of a small DC motor using a rotary encoder and an OPTO sensor, and counter input on myDAQ.

Here's my circuit on the breadboard:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The collector pin of the transistor is connected to the DIO1 port of the myDAQ.

And here's the LabVIEW code:

[image]

On the front panel, I only have the RPM numeric indicator.

When I run the program, with the rotary encoder spinning in the gap of the OPTO coupler, nothing happens. The RPM numeric indicator keeps showing 0.

I thought the problem was my OPTO coupler. I tested it through analog input and I successfully visualised the pulses, as shown here:

[image]

So the problem is not the OPTO coupler.

And I can't seem to figure out the source of the problem. I would really appreciate some help please.

Comment: Amplitude of **-5V**? I notice that breadboard connections to MyDaq use **blk** and **red** wires to the 5V power source. We usually connect **blk** to **GND** and **red** to **+5V**. You haven't followed this convention.

Comment: Show a schematic. Breadboard pictures do not constitute a circuit diagram.

Comment: Optocoupler is a word, not an abbreviation. There's no need to capitalize it or split it into two words.